# Cross-correlation significance in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, cross-correlation

How do you tell if the correlations at different lags obtained from the cross-correlation (ccf function) of two time series are significant.

Comment: Have a look at my question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1881/analysis-of-cross-correlation-between-point-processes

Comment: hi. I have one question. How can I test the significance of the correlation coefficient? I have two time series and I want to test if they are cross correlation . should I do prewhitening the two series before comuputing the ccf or there are an easy way?

Answer (score 24):

The variance of the cross-correlation coefficient under the null hypothesis of zero correlation is approx $1/n$ where $n$ is the length of the series. The coefficients are also asymptotically normal. So approximate critical values (at the 5% level) are $\pm 2/\sqrt{n}$.

These critical values are plotted automatically in R using `ccf(x,y)`.

Comment: Type the name of the function in the console. Otherwise, the source code for core R functions is all on svn. e.g., https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/acf.R

Answer (score 5):

The cross-correlation coefficient does not measure dependence between time series. The proper tool for it is the coherence function. For example, see Bendat and Piersol, 2010.

Comment: Do you mean Bendat and Piersol, 2000. Single-Input/Output Relationships. I could not find any article from those authors in 2010.

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/8/8.2

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/175646/48197