# How can I test the significance of the correlation coefficient?

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-correlation significance in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/cross-correlation-significance-in-r)

How can I test the significance of the correlation coefficient? I have two time series and I want to test if they are cross correlation. Should I do prewhitening  the two series before comuputing the ccf or there are an easy way?