# How to test significance of vector with correlation coefficients

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance, t-test, cross-correlation

I am new to R so please apolozige if I should use wrong terms etc.

Let's say I investigated married couples as subjects, and (amongst other) tested if their amount of consumed alcohol is correlated to each other. For this, I assed amount of alcohol consumed every day for a year, for both wife and husband in diffrent couples. I then assessed the cross-correlations (ccf function in R) for each couple.

I now have a vector containing cross-correlations coefficient (at lag 0) between the wife's amount of consumed alcohol and the husband's amount of consumed alcohol for each of the tested couples:

```
[1] 0.15
[2] 0.03
[3] 0.17
[4] -0.33
```

...
and so on (total of 200 subjects).

I now want to test, if these correlations are significantly greater than 0, using a t-test. 
Does this make sense? 
If yes, how can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Since you run a cross correlation the critical values (at the 5% level) are $± 2/ \sqrt[]{n}$. In your case the critical values are <0.1414214 and >0.1414214. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/cross-correlation-significance-in-r).

Also keep in mind that for lag 0 you can simply use the Pearson correlation in `cor()`. See here:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(200)
y <- x* .2 + rnorm(200)

corcoef <- ccf(x, y, lag.max = 0)[["acf"]]
corcoef
0.1605629
cor(x, y)
0.1605629
```

This means that if you are interested about lag= 0 you can use `cor.test()` which shows $p$ value. Here:

```
cor.test(x, y)
p-value = 0.02313
...
```