# Determine confidence interval in a 2D cross correlation map

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-correlation, 2d

My problem is as follows:

I have a 2D image (u,v), with each pixel representing the value of the 2D cross correlation function (ccf) at that place. I am trying to determine to what degree I can be confident that the ccf peak is in that region. Specifically I have identified the peak pixel (I, J), around which all other pixels have lower values, like a 2D gaussian function. I am drawing a circle of radius R. My question is, how long must R be, so that I achieve a 95% confidence level.

I would suppose that the answer is something along the lines discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/cross-correlation-significance-in-r), but this is for 1D.

Any help/answer is greatly appreciated.