# Computing correlation (and the significance of said correlation) between a pair of time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have two time series S, and T. they have the same frequency and the same length.

I would like to calculate (using R), the correlation between this pair (i.e. S and T), and also be able to calculate the significance of the correlation), so I can determine whether the correlation is due to chance or not.

I would like to do this in R, and am looking for pointers/skeletal framework to get me started.

Comment: Are the time series both stationnary ? www.econ.ohio-state.edu/dejong/note1.pdf

Comment: @kwak: No, the series are both NOT stationary.

Comment: Here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1881/analysis-of-cross-correlation-between-point-processes I was proposing a Monte Carlo approach to determine confidence limits. The idea was to do this for two point processes, but I guess it could be easily adapted for your situation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ccf function to get the cross-correlation, but this will only give you a plot.  If the estimated cross correlations fall outside the dash red line, then you can conclude that there is a statistically significant cross-correlation.  But I do not know of a package with a formally encapsulated test.  Example from ccf doc:

```
require(graphics)

## Example from Venables & Ripley (Provided in  CCF help file)
ccf(mdeaths, fdeaths, ylab = "cross-correlation")
```

Note, that the question of significance test is also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/cross-correlation-significance-in-r).

Comment: Other posters have noted that stationarity is important here. If both series have a linear upwards trend (one kind of nonstationarity), they will be correlated - but all the correlation may be due to the common trend, which may or may not be what we are interested in.

Answer (score 4):

How do you define correlation for non stationary time series? Do you plan to take the correlation of the diff or these time series?
If not, I suggest you look for cointegration rather than correlation (cf Granger etc...)