# How to calculate p-value for Cross-Correlation for two time series with delay?

Tags: time-series, p-value, cross-correlation, c++

I have two stationery time series that I want to see are they correlated or not. I decided to work with cross correlation, there is a good answer in [Correlation between two time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29096/correlation-between-two-time-series) but I dont know how to calculate p-value(as https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11032/michael-chernick said) and decide that its a good answer, if there are correlated do something. I dont know how to do this.
I want to code it with C++ and use it for simulation in Omnet++ .
Could someone help me to find a way or introduce a document to me to understand the mathematical way to calculate it and program it in C++? 
P.s : My data are the number of packets which send from two nodes to an OLT in a network continuously. something like this:

from time 0 to 10:

series 1 : 2 5 3 7 9 2 0 1 8 4
 series 2: 3 4 6 0 5 9 2 5 3 7  . series 2 has 6 min delay. or maybe there is no delay in other case, I must calculate the delay also (I can calculate delay with omnet++ but I dont know are they correlated at the end or not)