# Partial Cross-correlation in R

Tags: r, cross-correlation, partial-correlation

I think the title is fairly self-explanatory. I want to compute the cross-correlation between two time series controlled for the values at other lags. I can't find any existing code to do this, either in R or any other language, and I'm not at all confident enough in my knowledge of statistics (or R) to try to write something myself. It would be analogous to the partial autocorrelation function, just for the cross-correlation instead of the autocorrelation.

If it helps at all, my larger objective is to look for lagged correlations between different measurements of a physical system (to start with, flux and photon index from gamma ray measurements of blazars), with the goal of building a general linear model to try to predict flaring events.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29096/correlation-between-two-time-series

Comment: Not really, computing the cross-correlation itself isn't difficult. It's possible that I'm misunderstanding something about partial correlations and how the idea can be applied to cross-correlations, but I don't have any problem just computing the plain cross-correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

After performing the same experiment as below but using `pacf` both in its [matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292271/does-the-partial-version-of-the-cross-correlation-function-exist-if-so-how-can/292290#292290) and univariate versions, the results as Ben says in his comments, are, despite close in magnitude and sign, inconsistent with regards to the univariate PACF.

After looking at the algorithm to compute the partial cross-correlation (Wei, 1990) implemented in R, I came to the conclusion that it is not the same one as the one used for a univariate PACF. This is because it uses a system of equations to solve the covariance matrix structure betweeen x & y, and so results from the matrix `pacf` may differ slightly from the standard version of `pacf`. This is also why Ben got an error when trying `pacf(cbind(x,x))`, because the covariance matrix is singular (perfectly collinear) and the equation system has no explicit solution. See the [code of my own answer to this question in another post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292271/does-the-partial-version-of-the-cross-correlation-function-exist-if-so-how-can/292290#292290)
[image: PCCF]

[image: PACF]

Numeric results:

```
> pacf(ts(cbind(x,y)), lag.max = 10)$acf
, , x

              x           y
1  -0.003727913  0.09929345
2  -0.019429467  0.09901536
3  -0.094662076 -0.08654108
4  -0.115294825  0.05975806
5  -0.102362997  0.03858411
6  -0.149191058 -0.12823916
7   0.033546670  0.01312224
8   0.014324840  0.10429490
9  -0.040499352  0.09112193
10 -0.016651355  0.19938648

, , y

              x           y
1  -0.072296936 -0.08924322
2  -0.078223312  0.06256214
3  -0.031792998  0.08157497
4  -0.037541212  0.02807893
5  -0.031197429  0.17576577
6  -0.163777892  0.04700697
7  -0.096232203  0.17346797
8   0.074688604 -0.16685102
9   0.142284523  0.21034469
10 -0.005083913 -0.08787128

> pacf(x,lag.max = 10)$acf
, , 1

              [,1]
 [1,] -0.003651251
 [2,] -0.027034679
 [3,] -0.107610793
 [4,] -0.115848824
 [5,] -0.104851323
 [6,] -0.153474662
 [7,]  0.023496026
 [8,] -0.002487242
 [9,] -0.024917174
[10,] -0.004873933
```

I'll leave the next (earliest) explanation for informative purposes, although it was not what Ben was asking for:

===================================================================

```
set.seed(1)
x=rnorm(100)
y=rnorm(100)
acf(ts(cbind(x,y)), lag.max = 10)$acf
ccf(x,y,lag.max = 10)$acf
```

The output of the acf is:

```
, , 1

              [,1]          [,2]
 [1,]  1.000000000 -0.0009943199
 [2,] -0.003651251  0.0931958052
 [3,] -0.027020987  0.0838231520
 [4,] -0.107330672 -0.0846397759
 [5,] -0.112573012  0.0625416141
 [6,] -0.093379369  0.0102113266
 [7,] -0.124715177 -0.1158511804
 [8,]  0.064980847  0.0140146020
 [9,]  0.043035067  0.0842043416
[10,]  0.025965230  0.0805874051
[11,]  0.024651027  0.1577061350

, , 2

               [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] -0.0009943199  1.000000000
 [2,] -0.0770969065 -0.089335795
 [3,] -0.0752198505  0.063139650
 [4,] -0.0285379520  0.053629242
 [5,] -0.0352903171  0.016052174
 [6,] -0.0165617885  0.169277776
 [7,] -0.1527458267  0.008381153
 [8,] -0.0518997943  0.166212699
 [9,]  0.0909969284 -0.179222389
[10,]  0.1243573098  0.243623031
[11,] -0.0077009885 -0.075363415
```

The output of the ccf is (I highlighted row 11 for explanation purposes):

```
, , 1

               [,1]
 [1,]  0.1577061350
 [2,]  0.0805874051
 [3,]  0.0842043416
 [4,]  0.0140146020
 [5,] -0.1158511804
 [6,]  0.0102113266
 [7,]  0.0625416141
 [8,] -0.0846397759
 [9,]  0.0838231520
[10,]  0.0931958052
**[11,] -0.0009943199**
[12,] -0.0770969065
[13,] -0.0752198505
[14,] -0.0285379520
[15,] -0.0352903171
[16,] -0.0165617885
[17,] -0.1527458267
[18,] -0.0518997943
[19,]  0.0909969284
[20,]  0.1243573098
[21,] -0.0077009885
```

In order to compare both outputs, one must consider that `acf` computes the univariate ACFs for x & y on the diagonal of the output (that is[,,1][,1] and [,,2][,2]) and the cross-correlation in the anti-diagonal (that is[,,1][,2] and [,,2][,1]).

On the other hand, the built-in `ccf` computes the cross-correlation between both series and their lagas, and outputs it in one single matrix, with lag 0 (instantaneous correlation) being its midpoint value (in our example, value [11,]). This value is the first value of each anti-diagonal matrix in the `acf` results.

From here it is straightforward to see that:

- if we are comparing the lags of x vs y we will be looking at the first anti diagonal matrix `([,,1][,2])`, and reading the ccf from the 11th value up until the 1st one;
- and for the comparison of the lags of y vs x, we will be looking at the second `([,,2][,1])` anti-diagonal matrix, and correspondingly at the ccf we will read from the 11th until the 21st value. This yields the same exact results when you compare the outputs.

Comment: Here, you're computing an autocorrelation and cross-correlation, though. I was asking about a partial cross-correlation. Comparing the partial autocorrelation to the output of the code you gave in your other answer produces inconsistent results. Supposing your method yields a partial cross-correlation, then for any x it should be that pacf(x)=pacf(ts(cbind(x,x))). However, pacf(ts(cbind(x,x))) produces a singular matrix error. Also, in the output plots of pacf(ts(cbind(x,y)) (with x!=y), the plot for x alone does not resemble the output of pacf(x). Am I interpreting the output wrong?

Comment: @Ben very right so, it does produce a singular matrix error. I can only guess (very farfetchedly), that this error is due to the computation using Wei's algorithm for PCCF that I included in my question [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292271/does-the-partial-version-of-the-cross-correlation-function-exist-if-so-how-can). I guess (may be wrong) that when R tries to solve the system of equations dependent on the covariance matrix of x, since x is the same, the system is singular (i.e. perfectly collinear), and throws an error

Comment: @Ben so, I cannot really state for sure what is going on here, but looking at the results, and knowing where they are coming from, I would trust the method implemented in R. Wei's algorithm for partial correlation is different than that of standard partial autocorrelation. For more info I can only refer you to Wei's 1990 Time Series Analysis book, and to dig into the wikipedia page for the computation of partial autocorrelation

Answer (score 3):

Look at my [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292271/does-the-partial-version-of-the-cross-correlation-function-exist-if-so-how-c)  to my own question (same as the one you posted).

You can make use of the `pacf` function in R, extending it to a matrix with 2 or more time series. I have checked results between the multivariate `acf` and `ccf` functions and they yield the same results, so the same can be concluded about the multivariate `pacf`and the non-existing `pccf`.

Comment: I tried your method of doing `pacf(ts(cbind(x,y)))` and I'm not sure it's correct. I tested it with a random normal vector and got inconsistent results. Firstly, it throws an error if x=y. But try `x=rnorm(100)`, `y=rnorm(100)` and compare the output of your code to `pacf(x)` and `pacf(y)`.

Comment: @Ben check out my answer below

Comment: @Ben I just realised I did it with the ACF instead of PACF. I ran the test with `pacf`and to my surprise it does yield inconsistent results. I cannot figure out why though. Nonetheless, although weird, the correlation matrices show close results both in magnitude and sign of the partial correlations. Will look into this matter a bit further and try to figure out why