# R correlation between two time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

This is my very first post on CV so comment if I can improve my post.

I have two webs that sell very similar products and also have a very similar group of customers.

I was trying to prove that concept that "Fast Moving Inventory From Web A Will Also Move Fast on Web B"

I have the daily snapshots of the inventory of both WebA and WebB. For example, for the product A from Web A, data looks like this:

```
TimeStamp  Product  Stock  UnitPrice
Oct 1st    A        100    1.2
Oct 2nd    A        90     1.2
Oct 3rd    A        40     1.2
Oct 4th    A        240    1.2
..
```

For those two Webs, some of their products are exactly the same. For example, WebA and WebB both have product A. I am wondering is there a way to use R to do some time series analysis so I can prove that for those products that they have in common. There is a very high correlation (WebA sell product A crazy last weekend, which is also a good sale reflected on Web B's data)?

Is there some R functions to do what I want? Then I can tell Web B that you need to carry those top selllers of Web A but Web B doesn't carry now.

Comment: This could be a helpful start: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3463/24000

Comment: Also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26846/24000